# Heads-up: Off-topic twice in filter menu

Tags: bug, status-completed

As I noticed on both [Ask Ubuntu](https://Askubuntu.com) and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) that the word "off-topic" was appearing twice in the filter when working the close queue:

[image: Off-topic²]

I directly took it to [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327757/off-topic-twice-in-filter-menu) as it wasn't just limited to Ask Ubuntu and [they're working on it already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327757/off-topic-twice-in-filter-menu?noredirect=1#comment1070096_327757) so if you'd see this: `SET IGNORE_MODE=ON`

#### ;-)

Comment: P.S. Can one of the mods add tag [status-review] as I can't...

Comment: That should only be added by devs since this is a bug report.  **All moderators other than SE Staff/Devs: Do not add any status tags to this, let the Devs handle that**

Comment: [This is fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327848/275497)